# I want all the employee names when i used a particular department id

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am using this code to save all the employee data when i selected  a particular department (name) and use that department name (fetching their department id) and using that id to search all the employee data or all the employee data which is similar to that department id is saved into array and print that.
But when i used that code, it prints employee id nil and print all the employee name(for all department id)

[API data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW4ct.png)

```
if let deptt = dictData["departments"] as? [Any] {

                print(deptt)

                for i in deptt as! [[String : Any]]
                {
                    let depttName = i["name"] as? String
                    let depttID = i["id"] as? String
                    //print(i["name"]!)

                    if depttName == selectedDeptt
                    {
                        let emp = dictData["employees"] as? [Any]

                        for j in emp as! [[String : Any]]
                        {
                            let empID = j["department_id"] as? String
                            let empName = j["name"] as? String

                            print("Employee ID is : \(String(describing: empID))")

                            if depttID == empID
                            {
                                print("Employee ID is : \(String(describing: empID))")
                                print("Employee Names : \(String(describing: empName))")
                                arrEmp.append(empName!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: let deptPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "department_id == %@", "4")
let filteredArray = (arrayofDictionary as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(deptPredicate)

Comment: `let names = arrayOfDictionary.filter({ $0['department_id'] == 2 }).map({ $0['name']`

Comment: `if let employees = dict["employees"] as? [[String:Any]]{let employees4 = employees.filter({($0["department_id"] as? Int) == 4}).map{$0["name"]}}` can do the trick. Now you may still want to tell us what you've tried, and I'd suggest to serialize with custom objects your JSON with a Employee class to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

// Consider a dictionary with key "Employee" and value of type [Employee]

```
let dict = ["Employees":[Employee(deptId:"4",id: "2", name: "Naman"),Employee(deptId:"3",id: "3", name: "Ayush Agrawal"),Employee(deptId:"4",id: "5", name: "Manish")]]
```

//get array of employee

```
let employeeArray = dict["Employees"]
```

//set dept id

```
let deptId = "4"
```

//Apply filter based on deptId

```
let filteredArray = employeeArray?.filter({ (emp) -> Bool in
    emp.deptId == deptId
})
```